# Wrong type inference of higher-order function argument type

Tags: typescript, types, type-inference

Say I want to write function that accepts object of some type T and another value, which type P should be somehow restricted by T, for example P should be array of keys of T.

I can easily write it:

```js
function bar<T, P extends keyof T>(obj: T, p: P[]) {
  // use p to index obj somehow
  return obj;
}

bar({ a: 1, b: 'foo' }, ['a']); // Ok
bar({ a: 1, b: 'foo' }, ['a', 'b']); // Ok
bar({ a: 1, b: 'foo' }, ['a', 'b', 'c']); // Error: 'c' is not valid key
```

Imagine then I want to use that function as argument of higher-order method, that should accept it alongside with second parameter `arg` and just call it with `this` and `arg`:

```js
class Indexed {
  constructor(public a: number = 1) {}
  public app<P>(f: (obj: this, arg: P) => this, arg: P) {
    return f(this, arg);
  }
}

const a = new Indexed().app(bar, ['a']); // Error, `Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"a" | "app"'.`
const a = new Indexed().app(bar, ['wtf']); // The same
```

If I use `bar` directly, everything works as expected:

```js
bar(new Indexed(), ['a']); // Ok
bar(new Indexed(), ['wtf']); // Err, as expected
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAIwIYCcA8AVANIgBUQFMAPKYsAEwGdEBrYgTzmEWwD4AKOZAKwBc7fAAchBANoBdAJSIA3gChEiAPSrEIGsUQjEUOIhjUyiXn0Q04AW2IALOAHdlidMSgh0ScwG5FAX0VFNHQueURUIQBGfGQhAHJgODh4xH98CXjUeNk-ELCI6NiEpJS0jKz4-HjkHJk8jALIxBiUEuTU9MRM7Ora6og6v0UIABtUGjoASRNSYioFFwgEGih0EGg4UJEQZFGYCELEMBBrZGJ0RABeFrl5QJUdvYOIkRFMAm5gIR5+ISg7DAaPgMABzcRyK4cfSA4ERdDgwh3FwqNweLyIYBcAFAkEI+ouQKBEYrKARa7HYiORAzKhkeZcGQAOlQby4IQq2VyQWCjTAVJpswZMk5Q15oX51Np9KojIqtVyQA)

The question is: how to write `app` such that it will accept/reject arguments the same way `bar` does it?

Note that in general I don't know restrictions of `bar` apriori, so I cannot restrict `P` with the same bounds as in `bar`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is just a case where TypeScript widens `["foo","bar"]` to `string[]` because it doesn't realize you need the type to stay a tuple of string literals `["foo", "bar"]` (or at least an array of string literals `Array<"foo"|"bar">`).  In your `bar()` function, `P` being constrained to `keyof` anything hints the compiler not to widen string literals to string, but no such hint exists for `P` in `Indexed.app()`.

Either you need to come up with a way to modify the `Indexed.app()` signature so as hint that `P` should inferred in a narrow way where possible without actually constraining it (since you don't know what `P` will be, as you said), or you need to come up with a way to hint/specify that `P` should be narrow when you *call* `Indexed.app()`.

---

Modifying the signature of `app()` to do this currently requires some weird tricks, and until and unless this [changes](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30680), it looks like this:

```
type Narrowable =
  | string
  | number
  | boolean
  | symbol
  | object
  | undefined
  | void
  | null
  | {};

class Indexed {
  constructor(public a: number = 1) {}
  public app<
    N extends Narrowable,
    P extends N | [] | { [k: string]: N | P | [] }
  >(f: (obj: this, arg: P) => this, arg: P) {
    return f(this, arg);
  }
}

const a = new Indexed().app(bar, ["a"]); // okay
const b = new Indexed().app(bar, ["wtf"]); // error "wtf" not assignable to "a"|"app"
```

---

Hinting at the call site is less ugly, if the caller remembers to do it:

```
class Indexed {
  constructor(public a: number = 1) {}
  public app<P>(f: (obj: this, arg: P) => this, arg: P) {
    return f(this, arg);
  }
}
const a = new Indexed().app(bar, ["a" as "a"]); // okay
const b = new Indexed().app(bar, ["wtf" as "wtf"]); // error "wtf" not assignable to "a"|"app"
```

Or you could forget the hint and just specify the type parameter yourself manually:

```
const c = new Indexed().app<["a"]>(bar, ["a"]); // okay
const d = new Indexed().app<["wtf"]>(bar, ["wtf"]); // error "wtf" not assignable to "a"|"app"
```

---

Okay, hope one of those helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAIwIYCcA8AVANIgBUQFMAPKYsAEwGdEBrYgTzmEWwD4AKOZAKwBc7fAAchBANoBdAJSIA3gChEiAPSrEIGsUQjEUOIhjUyiXn0Q04AW2IALOAHdlidMSgh0ScwG5FAX0VFNHQueURUIQBGfGQhACJgODh4xH98CXjUeNkfNQ0AeXpgjDCI6NiEpJS0jKz4-HjkHJk89UQiktDwyMQYlCrk1PTETOzG5saIFraNAFF0dDh0IQByCFWjOjA4KEQAN1QAGxgqBmYgsFRbGhFUCB0AZRgAcyuPN2eqHSUVKCYRDoAHIYJaOVDII46AC8LhUAB9LFB0MYXnDEIiwCBrMhiOh0YjkMkoagwATLEwcXAjuTzMRoOTwN9gMZiFRyfs4KdyVijjSVAiFP4-C4IEdUDQ6ABJEykNkKdEQBA0ZEgaDLLgiECQmAQcqILE4vGIaF9OTyQIC3Tak561AiESYdEqIEkciUWiIEGLJwQqG4Z2EN0Uah0V2I6QYhSjehCFUosAvKRCcNBiNSNLo7jAIQ8fhCKB2GA0fAYF7iOTQjj6IsliLocuEc2BtwfJDALiF4ulhutdGWzOi5V7VAmg3ERyIGXfOVULgyAB09pEXBCdWyuXyZnoqCYQ7AKpQY7AE6nsrZ86XDtXGDqjigwBmW7xS3QiHi98fBt2EUlryukI6AY77ZPCWQOvEASXNcxC3PcOgAMLHEcXw-KK4qSmeM7yr8ApKgeqrqqEWo6naQiGrib6mlE5oDioJG2hEDqYAQ2a5uYBa1j2jYEJW1ZdnWZYVgqVoqK2njtp2XH1i8fZWgOA7tEWYBQPuh6jqaJ6TtOZAXouy43ug66pBKIFPu0cA7nuKj4YeyDHqeOmzpeBlrqMH4PiZdAeY+m7tC+yzvp+qQ7COf5vH6QGGPUYHLpBKjtLc9IwMA1mILZex6ppjnnnO+nMWMOTcG5hV+Rolm7mpexnNl2m5S5BU+UVhl3p5ZUkD6b5Nd+YU0P+kX6NFoHgSIkGBEAA)